# trouble-shooting non-finite values (stat_smooth)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm able to plot two time series for cost and income by date

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- a %>% 
  select(date, cost, inc) %>% 
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value", -date)
```

Data:

```
  date      variable  value
1 2019-07-09 cost 103.00
2 2019-07-09 cost 80.00
3 2019-07-09 cost 17.00

. . .

1707 2019-07-18 inc 0.00
1708 2019-07-18 inc 0.00
1709 2019-05-01 inc 53737.65
1710 2019-07-01 inc 11812.35
1711 2019-09-01 inc 19135.57
1712 2019-10-01 inc 1973.96
1713 2019-11-01 inc 25711.09
1714 2020-03-01 inc 37454.77
```

Code for plotting:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
  geom_area(aes(color = variable, fill = variable), 
            alpha = 0.5, position = position_dodge(0.8)) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800")) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#00AFBB", "#E7B800"))
```

[image: income and cost by date]

but when I try to add a trend smooth line, I get the following message:

> "Removed 6 rows containing non-finite values (stat_smooth) appear to be the values in "inc".

```
p + stat_smooth(color = "#FC4E07", fill = "#FC4E07", method = "loess")'
```

[image: non-finite values removed]

If that's right then is there a way to scale these values or is something else going-on?

Comment: Without seeing your actual `ggplot()` call, it is hard to see what your `x` and `y` variables for the smoothing function (and whether or not a `group`ing variable is applied).  I am assuming that they are `date` and `value`, which would mean that at most 6 of your rows has incomplete data for at least one of the variables.

Comment: thanks, I'll keep searching for incomplete data

Comment: It would also be easier to assist if you provided a reproducible example with data (if possible) and all of the code used.

Comment: Not doing well with my first question!